# Sun light pass through the walls and flickering when navigating in viewport

Tags: unreal-engine5

I am using geometry brush to create an inner box and a outer box. the inner is set to **brush type ‘substractive’** results in a simple room like this:
[image]

then i create several windows using the same substractive way:

[image]

now the sunlight behave very wired : **it pass through the solid wall** and **flickering** show in my room when i navigate or rotate my camera view.

[image]

this is absoutely some glitch, but i don’t know how to fixed this so that the sun light behave more stable instead of coming and going unexpectedly when navigate in the room.

Any feedback would be appreciated

I have try to adjust some parameters of the sun light setting, but still not working

Comment: If you do not convert from brushes to geometry, you have to be aware that there are a lot of lighting limitations on brushes. You can see that they will also appear weird in some of the lighting view modes.